# Is there a "-nym" word for the members of a political party?

Tags: single-word-requests

In [an answer to a previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/210511/55623), I referred to "*tea-partiers*" as the *demonym* for members of the Tea Party in US politics.

But I know that's not right; *demonym* describes the name of the population of a physical *place*.

Is there a corresponding *-nym* or otherwise short, self-contained word for members of a political party or other abstract group?

Comment: Ideologies (esp, radical ones, or those the speaker is scornful of) are often collectively referred to as ***isms***. An adherent of ***XXXism*** is an ***XXXist***.

Comment: True, good point, but in this case I'm specifically looking for a clinical, value-judgement-free term (so that my scorn doesn't bleed through).

Comment: [taxonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-onym) Comment because Wikipedia is not a source.

Comment: I would call them Tea Partisans.

Comment: @SrJoven, it's definitely worth adding that as a answer for "A *-nym* word for ... abstract group". I'll upvote it at least.

Comment: **friends**? - a member of the same nation, party, etc - [DR](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/friend)

Comment: @ermanen, I'm looking for a word which describes a word - a metaword. Just as "*tea partiers*" describes "*members of the Tea Party*", I'm looking for a word which, in turn, describes "*tea partiers*". Make sense?

Comment: So, you can use "friends" for the members of a political party. It is a generic and a neutral term and can be a hypernym for "comrades","republicans","liberals" etc. (not a -nym word but I think there isn't a -nym word for this).

Comment: @ermanen The problem is that I am trying to talk about the *word* "tea partiers" and how it is pluralized. I am not trying to talk about the political party or its members. I want a word -- which doesn't have to end in *-nym* -- to talk about the *word* "tea partiers", or the *word* "republicans", etc.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-onym) says that a *taxonym* is:

> a name used for classification or identification purposes, usually signifying a relationship to something.

Which, is about as generic as you can get, plus it has that word *tax* in it, so of course it fits, right?

Comment: Ha! I didn't even think of the *tax* element. If I had another +1, I'd award it just for that.